# I don't know when i have to use centerx and centry

Tags: python, pygame

i have one important question i started doing project now, and i don't really know what's the difference between centerx and centry, for now I only see that centry is using for top and bottom, and centerx using right and left, can someone explain me more about it? I'm using pygame, if you have more valuable information you can share, I will be greatful :)

Comment: Are they related to a certain character or obejct? they are the `(x,y)` coordinates relative to the pygame window, where the `(0,0)` is at the top-left of the window. That's why changing x will move the object left or right and centery to the top or to the bottom. Is this what you are looking for? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`centerx` is the center of the `Rect` along the x axis. It's calulated by `Rect.x + Rect.w/2`.

Likewise, `centery` is the center of the `Rect` along the y axis.  It's calulated by `Rect.y + Rect.h/2`.

So if you have a `Rect` with `x=100` and `y=200` and `height=50` and `width=50`, `centerx` will be `125` and centery will be `225`.

Since you can also set these attributes, it's quite easy to align a `Rect`. So if you e.g. want to place a `Rect` in the middle of the bottom of the screen, you can so something like:

```
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
# you could also use my_rect.midbottom =s creen_rect.midbottom instead
my_rect.centerx = screen_rect.centerx
my_rect.bottom = screen_rect.bottom
```